# how to reset the zoom level of the image to original?

Tags: android, image, zooming

I need to set the zoom level of the image (in an `ImageView`) to the original state i.e where it just fits into the `ImageView` and all the zoom-in has been removed. what i have tried is to store the image matrix value at the time of opening the image (when it was fit to screen) and then on a 'reset' button click assign this value to the `ImageView` that was zoomed in (and might have a modified  matrix); but its not helping.. also i am not sure if its just the related matrix that defines the zoom level of the image or there is something else as well that i need to set. my code snippet:

PS. '`zoomMatrix`' is the image matrix at the time when the image has just opened n is fit to screen. 'touch' is the object of the class extending `ImageView`.

```
resetZoom.getItem().setOnMenuItemClickListener(

    new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            touch.setImageMatrix(touch.zoomMatrix);
            touch.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            touch.invalidate();

            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: did you try ScaleType.FIT_XY? i think that is no zoom thats what you want right?

Comment: yeah i tried that. it fits the image exactly into the screen. but then i cant zoom in or drag again. and yes i want no zoom (basically the very initial state my image).

Comment: maybe you should switch setscaletype and setimagematrix, is it in the right order?

Comment: tried that as well. no luck :( i tried touch.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE) also, it zooms out the image but then again i cant drag/zoom in again. and the if i tap a point on image,it gets dislocated.

Comment: can you set to fit_xy when you dont want to zoom and matrix when you want to zoom, like back and forth

Comment: i am using an imageview to open an image (some layout) and then the user can click/tap on the image; at this tap point i place a marker. now when i am trying to reset the zoom level of the image, the image gets to its original state but the when i try to zoom in or drag, the tap markers move but the image does not zoom in or gets draged. the markers should stay with the image whether we drag or zoom the image.

Comment: so it works as expected until you reset the zoom?

Comment: try to not setScaleType

Comment: yes it works until reset zoom.

Comment: but then how should i reset the zoom level??

Comment: maybe when you set the scaletype it resets the whole configuration

Comment: thats what i have tried.. what matrix value should i set the imageMatrix to?

Comment: it is already set to scaletype matrix before you reset right?

Comment: i mean if it was working before you reset the zoom, theres definetly a way that it should work after you reset the zoom, im confused

Comment: u r right. it is set to scaletype matrix before reset.

Comment: i wish i could do more for you, all i can advise is since it is working before reset, after you reset it, make sure everything is exactly how it was working from the begining

Answer (score -2):

you only need to do is,
to implement this simple code in your reset button

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
```

this will reset your activity to its original scale/position...